# How to make a pull request on project structure github

Tags: git, github

I have been assigned a task on Github for a repository that I own. I have added a collaborator to my repo and assigned him the title as, "reviewer." He has required that after adding all of my files/folders(without code in them) and committing, that I create a PR so that he can approve the project's structure. Below are his instructions:

**The structure of a project is simply creating all the folders and files you will need in the project. Below is the structure of the Flask Boggle App.**

[image]

**If you were required to create the project structure of the Flask Boggle App, you will only have to**

1. Create a branch,
2. Create all the project files and folders in the image above without any code. (Project Structure = The files and folders that will be holding all the code when the project is complete)
3. Commit the changes
4. Create a pull request.
5. Add a label.
6. Request for a review.

However, on Github, I am not given the option of creating a PR unless there have been changes/edits made to the branch. Once I upload all the files/folders, there is essentially nothing to even create a pull request on as all of the files are empty.

Comment: between step 3 and 4: push the changes to remote repo (github)

Comment: You would need to start with _some_ commit to make a pull request against, even if it's just an empty commit (`git commit -m 'Initial commit' --allow-empty` immediately after you `git init`).